# How can we delay a interface orientation change in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation, uiinterfaceorientation, uianimation

currently when i change the orientation of my app,all the entities on the screen are rendering one by one.This is looking a bit bad and i feel that this gives a bad user experience.
 Is there any way in which i can delay my orientation changes or may be create some kind of animation so that all the entities can be rendered at the same time in a single instance.

Comment: Describe more clearly what is in your app, what you're seeing on rotation, and what you want to see instead. "Entities"? More specific please!

Comment: @occulus: i am developing a ebook reader for iPad. I am displaying one page in portrait mode and 2 pages in lanscape mode. that means my page frame is something like (0,0,768,1024) in portrait and (0,0,512,768) and (0,512,512,768)in lanscape mode. im using drawLayer method to render these pages. Now when i rotate the device to landscape mode from portrait, two pages are rendering separately which is looking very abrupt... i want my pages to appear in a way similar to ibooks.. is there anything i can do about it ??